# GLSL shader to convert pixel colors as per the usecase

Tags: glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

In the code mentioned below, I want to accept 2 arguments **colors** & **activeColor**. **colors** array contains the list of allowed colors to be drawn in the image, **activeColor** is the selected color which is yet to be painted on image. I am using HTML5 canvas to paint on the top of image and WebGLShader to convert pixel colors as per the use-case.

While drawing(painting on canvas) a color my **use-case is to change other colors if present to activeColor**.

Written a basic logic below but it's not syntactically right. Help needed.

**colors**: dynamic Float32Array of colors ex: [0,0,0,1, 1,1,1,1] represents black & white color array

**activeColor**: dynamic Float32Array of color ex: [0,0,0,1] represents black color

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying float colors;
varying float activeColor;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, texCoord);

    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i+=3){
        vec4 c = vec4(colors[i], colors[i+1], colors[i+2], colors[i+3]);
        if(color.a > 0 && color.rgb != c) {
          color.rgb = vec4(activeColor[0], activeColor[1], activeColor[2], activeColor[3]);
        }
    }


    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: The type of `colors` is `float`. What do you expect by `colors.length`?

Comment: This might be helpful to you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529183/workaround-to-use-uniforms-or-similar-in-webgl-for-loops/32535139#32535139

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't make a lot of sense

```
varying float colors;
varying float activeColor;
```

Those are type `float` so they only old 1 value. They are not colors (vec4s) nor are they arrays.

```
colors.length
```

There is no such thing `someArray.length` in GLSL. In GLSL you can't pass variable sized arrays. They must be a fixed size. Similarly you can't pass in arrays as `varying`.

It's not clear what you're trying to do

Your code appears to be trying to draw activeColor everywhere the image does not contain the colors in `colors`.

You could do something like this

```
#define MAX_COLORS 10
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec4 colors[MAX_COLORS];
uniform int numColors;
uniform vec4 activeColor;
varying vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, texCoord);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; ++i) {
      if (i >= numColors) {
        break;
      }

      vec4 c = colors[i];
      if(color.a > 0 && color.rgb != c) {
        color.rgb = activeColor.rgb;
        break;
      }
    }

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

There's a limit on the number of uniform vec4s you can have. [It's between 29 and 4096](https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS) through looking at the stats you probably want to stay under 221.

It's more common to pass in arrays of data as textures.

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D colors;  // texture holding colors
uniform vec2 colorsSize;   // size of texture
uniform int numColors;
uniform vec4 activeColor;
varying vec2 texCoord;

vec4 getColor(int i) {
  vec2 pixelCoord = vec2(mod(float(i), colorsSize.x,
                         floor(float(i) / colorsSize.x));
  return texture2D(colors, vec2(pixelCoord + 0.5 / colorsSize));
}  

void main() {
    vec4 color = texture2D(texture, texCoord);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; ++i) {
      if (i >= numColors) {
        break;
      }

      vec4 c = getColor(i);
      if(color.a > 0 && color.rgb != c) {
        color.rgb = activeColor.rgb;
        break;
      }
    }

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Now you can pass in the colors as a texture.

You might find [these tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org) useful.

You might also find [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg#t=24m30s) semi related to your problem (replacing colors) for which there is a live example [here](https://webglsamples.org/color-adjust/color-adjust.html) and another explanation of the technique [here](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-post-processing-3dlut.html)