# How does one pass an array with no fixed size into the vertex shader?

Tags: javascript, arrays, webgl

I have an array with no fixed size (`let noise = [];`) in my .js file where it stores the noise values for a point (`noise[i]` -> a single point).

I was wondering if I'm able to pass all the values inside the array into my vertex.shader by doing:

```js
//.js
for(let i = 0; i < noise.length; i++) {
    const uNoise = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uNoise[" + i + "]");
    gl.uniform3fv(uNoise, MV.flatten(noise[i]));
}

//vertex.shader
let uNoise[];
```

If not, how would it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The locations of uniforms aggregated into arrays are ascending. Therefore you can simply do:

```js
const uNoise = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "uNoise");
gl.uniform1f(uNoise, new Float32Array(MV.flatten(noise)));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have variable sized arrays as uniforms in shaders.
What you could do is allocate an array of a fixed size that represents your maximum number of elements and then send an additional integer uniform with the actual element count.

```c
uniform int numElements;
uniform float noise[1024];
```

The you can use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529183/workaround-to-use-uniforms-or-similar-in-webgl-for-loops/32535139#32535139) to iterate through the values(if you need to).

Another approach would be to put the values in a texture and sample from that, if this is really just noise then you'd probably want to have a simple noise texture that just wraps around to begin with as it's a lot more comfortable to work with in a shader, on that note another alternative is to use an isomorphic pseudo-random function that you can run on the CPU and GPU to receive the same output when you put in the same data.

Comment: The objective is to apply random to a grid. Each grid point is a set of 2 points that are connected with gl.LINES, and then with noise I could apply it to every second point in the grid to create a pattern, resembling a flow field